# Is it ok mixing compiler option std=c++11 with older compiler options std=c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11

Upgraded C++ compiler to 4.8.5.
If linked with 2 different compiled objects std=c++11 and std=c++0x whether unpredictable behaviour possible?
The STL lib has 2 versions.
One for C++98 and another for C++11.
C++ STL shows 2 versions for each library function.
Whether STL will misbehave if linked with 2 different compiled objects

Comment: Assuming GCC, c++0x is an alias for c++11; they are the same thing.

Comment: There are subtle differences between different language versions, and interactions between different translation units compiled for different versions of C++ will not be subject to a single, brief, answer that will be universally true for every possible interaction between the two different versions of the language. In other words: your warranty is void because the sticker has been removed. Speaking of upgrades, I just upgraded to gcc 10, so I have `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17`, and `-std=c++20` at my disposal. I'm just recompiling all my stuff at C++20, and calling it a day.

Comment: You have easily ODR violation by using different version.

Comment: Hmm, judging by other comments I may have interpreted this question differently than others.  If you mean you have two object files, both compiled by GCC 4.8.5 with the only difference being one was compiled with `-std=c++0x` and the other was compiled with `-std=c++11` then you should have no problems.  Those are just two different ways to spell the same flag.  If you mean you have one object file compiled with GCC 4.8.5 using `-std=c++11` and another compiled using an _older_ version and `-std=c++0x` then you very well may have problems.

Comment: As a general rule; *all* objects that are linked together should be compiled with the exact same compiler using the same language standard. In rare cases some compilers give binary compatibility guarantees for some combinations, but that's the exception, not the rule.

Comment: "Upgraded C++ compiler to 4.8.5." - I assume that's GCC. That's a seriously ancient version to upgrade to. Latest is 10.1

Answer (score 1):

Usually, standards are backward compatible, however there are other things related to them that can break your code.

For example, in older standards (pre `C++11`) you couldn't use `-frtti`, and, if you use it, you will change physical memory layout for objects made from the same headers used by `C++98` and f.e. `C++11` compiled objects.

In some cases, you may need to add some flags to make your new objects  compatible/linkable with older-standard objects.

Comment: That backwards compatibility of the standard you mention is only *source compatibility* - as in; it'll usually work if you recompile your code - it's *not* ABI compatibility - C++ has never guaranteed that (some compilers provide such guarantees in some situations though).

Comment: @JesperJuhl You're right. I assumed few things here (f.e. all objects comiled with the same compiler). Also AFAIK GCC supports backward compatibility even without recompilation, f.e. GCC4.8 + GCC9 objects, as long as standard was 'fully implemented' in the used compiler (no guarantess for standard that was marked as experimental for given compiler release).

Comment: Here we are linking C++98 objects compiled with default option i.e. -std=c++98 and linking with  C++11 objects compiled with -std=c++11 option but with the same GCC version 4.8.5 on RHEL7 server.As all these objects are built with the same GCC version then they are ABI compatible, the standard version (i.e. the -std option) does it make any difference here ? Is safe to link together  combination of objects C++98,  C++11 built using the same GCC version on RHEL 7 server?